# Full name with valid email

Tags: php, regex

```
$string ='"Test User" <test@test.com>,"Another" <another@test.com>,"aeer" <whateveryourmail@gmail.com>';
```

I've succeed splitting this become pair of name and email address with this code

```
preg_match_all('!"(.*?)"\s+<\s*(.*?)\s*>!', $string, $matches);
```

the problem is, I can't validate the email address,false email address will be match too.
How to filter only valid email and also splitting Name and email address?

Comment: email validation has been discussed a several times on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+email+validation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use some of the available mail address parsers available, e.g.:

- [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php)
- [`Mail_RFC822::parseAddressList()`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-rfc822.parseaddresslist.php)

Optionally, filter the output through [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) (or one [of its permutations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) targeted at arrays) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`.

Comment: It seems like `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` [doesn't accept](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9afdc80d8ef16d2e7892d813953e0b11ed3f8f81) addresses like `Test User <test@test.com>`. Is there a way to get correct validation of those, too?

Answer (score 1):

E-mail address validation can be done in two ways: check for a @ and a . and assume it's valid. Users know their e-mail address, it is not our business if they enter a wrong one. If you want to be certain you make a good e-mail address checker, then there is only one correct regex to use for validation: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Answer (score 0):

What about jQuery?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqueryvalidate