# Extract a string between two characters

Tags: php, regex

I have an output string in this format `Fname Lname<fname@urmail.com>`. I want to extract the email from here. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can be sure that the string format is consistent, a simple regular expression will do the trick:

```
$input = 'Fname Lname<fname@urmail.com>';
preg_match('~<(.*?)>~', $input, $output);
$email = $output[1];
```

Comment: var_dump($output) results array(0) { }

Comment: @Tatu Instead of a lazy quantifier, use a negated character class and a greedy quantifier.

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Instead, use a parser. [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.mailparse-rfc822-parse-addresses.php) is made for this specific task by professionals with an in-depth knowledge of the subject (and the possible quirks that you *may* run into).

Example #1 from the docs:

```
$to = 'Wez Furlong <wez@example.com>, doe@example.com';
var_dump(mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses($to));
```

Gives (gentle formatting applied):

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["display"] => string(11) "Wez Furlong"
    ["address"] => string(15) "wez@example.com"
    ["is_group"] => bool(false)
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["display"] => string(15) "doe@example.com"
    ["address"] => string(15) "doe@example.com"
    ["is_group"] => bool(false)
  }
}
```

See also: [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist()`](https://www.php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) and *[Full name with valid email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014989/full-name-with-valid-email)*.

Comment: Note that mailparse is an PECL extension that is not bundled with PHP. Otherwise, this is the proper way to do this.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen True. The `php-imap` extension may be present, cf. updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use functions like substring and explode(easier method than regular expressions and will do the trick):

```
<?php
$text = 'Fname Lname<fname@urmail.com>';
$pieces = explode('<',$text);
$mail=substr($pieces[1],0,-1);
echo $mail;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should print the e-mail address:

```
if (preg_match("/<\S*>/", $subject, $matches)) {
  echo "E-Mail address: ".$matches[0];
}
```